# Delay Angular tests from starting?

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine

I have a proprietary 3rd party library that asynchronously injects some things into the `window` object that many of my Angular components depend on. Before my tests run, I need to wait for the 3rd party library to resolve it's promise. However, I can't seem to get the test runner to wait.

I am using Angular 10.

In my `test.ts` I have:

```
LoadAnnoyingBigBiznessStuff().then(() => {
    getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
      BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
      platformBrowserDynamicTesting(),
      {
        teardown: { destroyAfterEach: false },
      }
    );
  });
```

However, this causes an error when the tests run:

```
Error: Need to call TestBed.initTestEnvironment() first
```

This appears to occur because the script will complete while the promise resolves. It appears I cannot do top level `await` to try to wait for the async call to finish.

- https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/253#issuecomment-657277794
- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/23021

Is there a way I can delay the tests from running until some async procedure finishes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure this out on my own and it was easier than I thought. You're able to use jasmines `beforeEach` in `test.ts`.

```
//Use a subject to hold the ready state, initialized to false
const TEST_DELAY = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

//Call my async function that loads some stuff
LoadAnnoyingBigBiznessStuff().then(() => {
    getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
      BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
      platformBrowserDynamicTesting(),
      {
        teardown: { destroyAfterEach: false },
      }
    );

    //Tests are ready to run!
    TEST_DELAY.next(true);
});  

//This runs before each test.
beforeEach((done) => {
  TEST_DELAY .pipe(filter(isReady => !!isReady)).subscribe(_ => {
    done();
  });
});
```

The downside of this approach is you get a jasmine timeout error if your async function fails to return in a reasonable amount of time.